# what should be returned if the service could not implement

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

Suppose that I have a method which will transfer some money from a user to another user, but if the current balance is less than the amount of money that user wanted to transfer, it should not be able to transfer. what should be returned to show that the transaction is successfully implemented or not. what is the proper way to do this?

Service class

```
@Service
public class TransactionService {
    public TransactionService(){

    }
    public void transferBalanceToAccount(Account senderAccount, Account receiverAccount,Long transferBalance){   
        if(senderAccount != null && receiverAccount != null){
            // get both account balance
            Long senderCurrentBalance = senderAccount.getBalance();
            Long receiverCurrentBalance = receiverAccount.getBalance();

            if(senderCurrentBalance < transferBalance) {
                // i have no idea what to do
                return;
            }

            senderAccount.setBalance(senderCurrentBalance - transferBalance);
            receiverAccount.setBalance(receiverCurrentBalance + transferBalance);
        }
    }
}
```

Unit testing

```
@Test
    public void transferBalanceToAccountShouldNotBeAbleToTransfer(){
        // Arrange
        Account sender = new Account();
        sender.setBalance(0L);
        Account receiver = new Account();
        receiver.setBalance(100L);

        // Act
        transactionService.transferBalanceToAccount(sender, receiver, 10L);

        // Assert
        // I'm struggling
        assertEquals();
    }
```

Comment: You could throw an exception.

Comment: First `public boolean transferBalanceToAccount(`. But if you need more to know why the transfer can't be done, throw an Exception , defined by you that may contain more info.

Answer (score 2):

You should throw a custom Exception like `InsufficientFundsException` and handle it accordingly to your needs.
In test you can check for exception by e.g. changing the annotation. In JUnit:
`@Test(expected = InsufficientFundsException.class)`

Answer (score 1):

For REST API, you should be thinking about how you do it with a web site and HTML forms (the world wide web, after all, is the reference application for the [REST architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm)).

For an example like insufficient funds, we would be sending back a web page saying "we're sorry, there's not enough money for that".  The HTML representation would be in the message body of the response, because that's where the bespoke information belongs -- it is information addressed to the end client that is intended to be ignored by the general purpose components participating in the communication.

The status line and the headers are reserved for information from the "transfer documents over a network" domain that are expected to be understood by the general purpose components.

In this case, the message was handled correctly, but did not have the expected effect.  So we want to be using a 4xx Client Error status code.

Which one? [403 Forbidden](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) is a straight forward answer

> The 403 (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.  A server that wishes to make public why the request has been forbidden can describe that reason in the response payload (if any).

Another possibility is [409 Conflict](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8)

> The 409 (Conflict) status code indicates that the request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target resource.  This code is used in situations where the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.

For instance, in your example the user might be able to resolve the conflict by changing the amount of money in the request.

Mark Nottingham calls attention to the [special effects](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2017/05/11/status_codes) of a status code -- what will the general purpose components do differently?  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find rigorous definitions of these effects -- in some cases, there are hints about them scattered in the standard, but most of the time ????

Comment: isn't that responsibility of controller class?